# Java 2D Graphics Portability

Tags: java, awt

I have drawn a bar graph on a JPanel using commands such as g.fillRect(Color.Red). It is working perfectly on my computer; however, on many other machines, the colored rectangles dont show. Is there any compatibility issues surrounding java awt 2d graphics?

I am using Eclipse Luna on Windows vista with Java SDK 1.8.
I have tested it on a different machine with Eclipse Kepler 1.7 and it doesnt show. My friend used 1.8 Luna on a mac and they didnt show.

If there is any other information required, let me know. I will check this thread regularly.

Comment: Weird. Java programs should be portable to any OS.

Comment: If you are really using SWT (as indicated by the tag), then you need to make sure you're using the SWT library for your operating system.

Comment: apologies. its java.awt.graphics

Comment: Very unlikely.  More likely is a threading issue or some misuse of the drawing API.  Post your code.

Comment: *"If there is any other information required, let me know."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).